# Forcing Matlab to not overlap XTickLabels with YTickLabels

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there any way to prevent XTickLabels from overlapping with YTickLabels in a figure in Matlab?

Good:

[image]

Bad (-2 and -5 are overlapping):

[image]

---

Code (I would prefer a solution that is not customized to this particular piece of code):

Good:

```
wavelet_name = 'coif1';
[~,psi,xval] = wavefun(wavelet_name,10);
scale = 1;
shift = 1;
x_min = -1;
x_max = 8;
plot([x_min, shift+xval.*scale, x_max],[0, psi, 0]);
axis([x_min x_max -2 3]);
set(gca,'FontSize',50)
save_figure( [wavelet_name '_scale' num2str(scale) '_shift' num2str(shift)] )
```

Bad: (I only changed  `x_min = -1;` to `x_min = -5;`)

```
wavelet_name = 'coif1';
[~,psi,xval] = wavefun(wavelet_name,10);
scale = 1;
shift = 1;
x_min = -5;
x_max = 8;
plot([x_min, shift+xval.*scale, x_max],[0, psi, 0]);
axis([x_min x_max -2 2]);
%title('Sym2 Wavelet');
set(gca,'FontSize',50)
save_figure( [wavelet_name '_scale' num2str(scale) '_shift' num2str(shift)] )
```

I use Matlab R2014a with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: THis is not exactly a solution but a work around... you are using the `axis([])` command anyway,so why not change xmin or ymin a bit so that you have a bit more space between. Or you could easily use user specific labels/ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this problem has been fixed in Matlab R2014b. The execution of your code privides the following figure.

[image: wavefun]

Comment: Nice, that works great! I had almost upgraded to R2014b a few hours before I asked the question but eventually postponed it… the graphics system seems to have changed quite a lot! http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html Hopefully graphics are now a bit closer to publication quality than it used to be.